# echoing a variable inside a variable

Tags: variable, echo

In my environment, the following variable is set:

```
X=/home
```

so `echo $X` gives me `/home`

Now I set `Y=$X`

echo `$Y` gives me `$X`.

If I want to get `/home`  using `Y` is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried Y=$(echo $X)?

Comment: `echo $Y` doesnt produce `$X`. And dont do `Y=$(echo $X)`

Comment: @don_crissti - id wager the problem is when/where $X/$Y are set - and what the quote context is.

Comment: set Y=${X} and try

Comment: I think in `bash` it is ${!X} and ksh93 it is ${$X}. I have a shell function like `isname() case $1 in ([0-9]*|*[!_0-9[:alpha:]]*|'') ! :;;esac` that i typically use to verify that stuff though. `eval` works in all of em pretty much and the above is enough to validate safely.

Comment: I think i got the resolution. echo Y = `eval echo$X`

Comment: @RakeshJena - what? no! all you need to do is `x=value; y=$x; printf "%s\n" "$y"` to print `value` followed by a newline. if you want to store the name of a variable in the value of another like `x=value; y=x` and somehow get `value` out of `$y` then yes, it will require some kind of second evaluation - such as `eval` - but not in the way you described. its also important to validate `$y` before expanding its expansion - which is what `bash`'s `${!y}`, `ksh93`'s `${$y}` and `zsh`'s `${(P)y}` might conveniently do for you behind the scenes. But `x=value; y=x; eval "echo \"\$$y\""` == `value\n`

Comment: What shell is being used here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is possible. You can get your desired result using this

```
X='/home'
Y=$X
echo "$Y"
```

will produce the desired output

```
/home
```

For more http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html

Comment: `echo Y` will just print `Y`... and, no, there is nothing magical about `{}`.

Comment: @jasonwryan edited, Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you used single quote which prevent the variable from being evaluated , and keep it as str !

*you can put this usefull [function](https://gist.github.com/younes-hamada/3547f9fcdc0e1f9b0b2a) in your bashrc or anywhere you need*

```
setenv () 
{ 
    (($#)) && {
        [[ $# -gt 1 ]] && {
            local v=$1
            shift
            case "$@" in 
                *'('*) #check if array 
                    eval `echo $v=$@` ;
                    ;;
                *)
                    eval `echo $v="$@"` ;
                    ;;
            esac
        } || {
            eval echo "\$$1"
        }
    } || {
        echo "$FUNCNAME  set|get var|arr"
    }
}


younes@h:~$ setenv 
setenv set|get var|arr
younes@h:~$ setenv foo 'bar baz'
younes@h:~$ setenv foo
bar baz
younes@h:~$ setenv foo '(foo bar baz)'
younes@h:~$ setenv foo
foo
younes@h:~$ setenv {foo[@]}
foo bar baz
younes@h:~$ setenv {foo[0]}
foo
younes@h:~$ setenv {foo[1]}
bar
younes@h:~$ setenv {foo[2]}
baz
younes@h:~$ setenv {#foo[@]}
3
younes@h:~$
```